# InMobi onInterstitialFailed: An error occurred while fetching the ad

Tags: android

I'm trying to add inmobi interstitial in my android app. But I can't get it working with following error:

onInterstitialFailed: An error occurred while fetching the ad

I cannot find any solution. What's more strange I was already using inmobi in other apps and there it's working. But not in the new app. I've even tried to copy-paste all code + library (v. 4.5.3) and it's the same error.

Here's my code:

Initialization:

```
InMobi.initialize(_appActivity, IN_MOBI_PROPERTY_ID);
InMobi.setLogLevel(LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE);
```

Loading new ad:

```
IMInterstitial interstitial = new IMInterstitial(_appActivity, IN_MOBI_PROPERTY_ID);
interstitial.setIMInterstitialListener((IMInterstitialListener) _appActivity);
interstitial.loadInterstitial();

public void onShowInterstitialScreen(IMInterstitial arg0) {
        System.out.println("[INMOBI] onShowInterstitialScreen");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLeaveApplication(IMInterstitial arg0) {
        System.out.println("[INMOBI] onLeaveApplication");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismissInterstitialScreen(IMInterstitial arg0) {
        System.out.println("[INMOBI] onDismissInterstitialScreen");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialLoaded(IMInterstitial ints) {
        System.out.println("[INMOBI] onInterstitialLoaded");
        if (ints.getState() == IMInterstitial.State.READY){
            ints.show();
            System.out.println("ready, showing..");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialInteraction(IMInterstitial interstitial, Map<String, String> params) {
        System.out.println("[INMOBI] onInterstitialInteraction");       
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialFailed(IMInterstitial arg0, IMErrorCode arg1) {
        System.out.println("[INMOBI] onInterstitialFailed: " + arg1.toString());
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<!-- IN-MOBI -->
        <activity android:name="com.inmobi.androidsdk.IMBrowserActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard|smallestScreenSize|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.inmobi.commons.analytics.androidsdk.IMAdTrackerReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="com.inmobi.share.id" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.inmobi.commons.internal.ActivityRecognitionManager" />
```

I've even tried to change package name to the one of other apps where inmobi is working. Still the same error.

Yes, I've added permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Yes - I've tried test mode, adding testing devices (SODIN/ODIN1). I've also tried using another physical device. What's most strange in app diagnostics there's no traffic for this app: 0 valid and 0 invalid requests.

Yes I've tried new sdk (5.0.0) - still not working, but I'm getting error that property id is wrong (but I've it rechecked and it's ok) no matter which app property id I'd enter.

I've also contacted support, but got no answer.

Comment: Hey Makalele. Apologies for not seeing this earlier. I work at InMobi. Did you get this resolved? There was a bug in our earlier SDK but it has been fixed now so you shouldn't be seeing this issue.

Comment: Yes and I have no idea what I did wrong. I completely removed everything related to inmobi and started from scratch and then it worked.

Comment: Okay cool. In case you run into any problems, write to developer at inmobi dot com. Good luck with the app!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started integration from scratch and error never appeared again. No clue what was wrong though.